# Content-disposition filename "suggestion" is always ignored. Why?

Tags: c, cgi, content-disposition

This is a portion of a CGI program written in C. When the client clicks the link, I want the file to begin downloading, with the suggested default filename.

I know the spec clearly states that the filename specified in the Content-disposition header is merely SUGGESTED, but it seems no matter what browser I use, it's always ignored. I interpret that behavior to mean I'm doing something wrong.

Here is a stripped down code snippet that reproduces my problem. When compiled to, say, test.cgi the program works, but the browser saves the data with the filename "test.cgi" and not "archive.tar.gz" as suggested.

(File i/o error checking and other safe bits removed to keep this clear and brief.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CHUNK_SIZE 1024

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  int fd;
  long bytes_remaining, bytes_to_get, bytes_read, bytes_sent, retval;
  int chunksize;
  unsigned char data_buffer[CHUNK_SIZE];
  char header_str[200];

  fd = open( "archive.tar.gz", O_RDONLY );
  if( fd == -1 ) {
    printf( "Content-type: text/html\n\n" );
    printf( "Unable to open file: %s.<br><br>\n", strerror(errno) );
    return 0;
  }

  bytes_remaining = lseek( fd, 0, SEEK_END );
  lseek( fd, 0, SEEK_SET );

  snprintf( header_str, 200, "Content-Type: application/x-compressed\r\n\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"archive.tar.gz\"\r\n\r\n" );
  write( 1, header_str, strlen(header_str) );

  while( bytes_remaining > 0 ) {
    if( bytes_remaining > CHUNK_SIZE ) bytes_to_get = CHUNK_SIZE;
    else bytes_to_get = bytes_remaining;
    bytes_read = read( fd, data_buffer, bytes_to_get );
    bytes_sent = write( 1, data_buffer, bytes_read );
    bytes_remaining -= bytes_sent;
  }
  close( fd );

  return 0;
}
```

Why is my suggested filename consistently ignored?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you receive the value in the CGI? Provide a [mcve] and see [ask].

Comment: In the actual application, yes, the file to download is determined by parameters in the URL requested. The above is a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Compile it, put it on a server, request whatever_you_compiled_it_to.cgi, and instead of the browser downloading the file and naming it archive.tar.gz it gets saved as whatever_you_compiled_it_to.cgi.

Comment: No, it is not. There is the call missing, resp. the Website which results in calling it. You did not even answer what I asked.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. Your question was "Did you receive the value in the CGI?" What value are you talking about? Value of what? Take the code above. Stick it in a file called test.c. Compile it with gcc -o test.cgi test.c. Stick test.cgi on a web server. Put a file of random bits or something else called archive.tar.gz in the same directory. Type "http://thatserver.com/cgi-bin/test.cgi" into a browser. The browser will download the file archive.tar.gz but will save it to your computer as test.cgi, not archive.tar.gz as "suggested" by the Content-disposition header. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is an extra carriage return / newline in the header. It should be:

```
snprintf( header_str, 200, "Content-Type: application/x-compressed\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename=archive.tar.gz\r\n\r\n" );
```

As written in the OP, the Content-Disposition line would be interpreted as part of the data, not part of the header. Also, quotes around the suggested filename aren't needed.